# Extract Numeric data from the Column in Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with 20 columns and I want to update one particular column (whose data is null) with the data extracted from another column and do some formatting. Below is a sample input

```
+------------------------+----+
|col1                    |col2|
+------------------------+----+
|This_is_111_222_333_test|NULL|
|This_is_111_222_444_test|3296|
|This_is_555_and_666_test|NULL|
|This_is_999_test        |NULL|
+------------------------+----+
```

and my output should be like below

```
+------------------------+-----------+
|col1                    |col2       |
+------------------------+-----------+
|This_is_111_222_333_test|111,222,333|
|This_is_111_222_444_test|3296       |
|This_is_555_and_666_test|555,666    |
|This_is_999_test        |999        |
+------------------------+-----------+
```

Here is the code I have tried and it is working only when the the numeric is continuous, could you please help me with a solution.

```
df.withColumn("col2",when($"col2".isNull,regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_extract($"col1","([0-9]+_)+",0),"_",","),".$","")).otherwise($"col2")).show(false)
```

I can do this by creating a UDF, but I am thinking is it possible with the spark in-built functions. My Spark version is 2.2.0

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the current performance or did you try benchmarking the performance over scalable dataset?

Comment: Your solution only works when the numbers are contiguous, right? You write continuous, but I think you mean that they have to follow one another without other text in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UDF is a good choice here. Performance is similar to that of the `withColumn` approach given in the OP (see benchmark below), and it works even if the numbers are not contiguous, which is one of the issues mentioned in the OP.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import scala.util.Try

def getNums = (c: String) =>  {
    c.split("_").map(n => Try(n.toInt).getOrElse(0)).filter(_ > 0)
}
```

I recreated your data as follows

```
val data = Seq(("This_is_111_222_333_test", null.asInstanceOf[Array[Int]]),
               ("This_is_111_222_444_test",Array(3296)),
               ("This_is_555_666_test",null.asInstanceOf[Array[Int]]),
               ("This_is_999_test",null.asInstanceOf[Array[Int]]))
            .toDF("col1","col2")

data.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
```

Register the UDF and run it in a query

```
spark.udf.register("getNums",getNums)

spark.sql("""select col1,  
             case when size(col2) > 0 then col2 else getNums(col1) end new_col 
             from data""").show
```

Which returns

```
+--------------------+---------------+
|                col1|        new_col|
+--------------------+---------------+
|This_is_111_222_3...|[111, 222, 333]|
|This_is_111_222_4...|         [3296]|
|This_is_555_666_test|     [555, 666]|
|    This_is_999_test|          [999]|
+--------------------+---------------+
```

Performance was tested with a larger data set created as follows:

```
val bigData = (0 to 1000).map(_ => data union data).reduce( _ union _)
bigData.createOrReplaceTempView("big_data")
```

With that, the solution given in the OP was compared to the UDF solution and found to be about the same.

```
// With UDF
spark.sql("""select col1,  
             case when length(col2) > 0 then col2 else getNums(col1) end new_col 
             from big_data""").count

/// OP solution:
bigData.withColumn("col2",when($"col2".isNull,regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_extract($"col1","([0-9]+_)+",0),"_",","),".$","")).otherwise($"col2")).count
```

Comment: Hi, I think UDF will degrade the performance when compared with the in built functions. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: You would need to test to be certain, but regex processing is also expensive.

Comment: @SN_U: I added details of a performance comparison. TL;DR the UDF solution is only slightly faster, but it's easy to address the issue of non-contiguous numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, please check the performance.

```
df.withColumn("col2", expr("coalesce(col2, array_join(filter(split(col1, '_'), x -> CAST(x as INT) IS NOT NULL), ','))"))
  .show(false)

+------------------------+-----------+
|col1                    |col2       |
+------------------------+-----------+
|This_is_111_222_333_test|111,222,333|
|This_is_111_222_444_test|3296       |
|This_is_555_666_test    |555,666    |
|This_is_999_test        |999        |
+------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. My Spark version 2.2.0. It's giving a parse exception. I think this works for spark 2.4+ version. Could you please let me know for a solution which works in 2.2.0.